# Sort an array of type UnitMass

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

So i want to sort an array of UnitMass, but i want to sort it in a specific layout. I know how to sort it alphabetically, but that's not quite what i want anyone that know how i can do this?

Is it possible to sort an array like this, and how can i do this or could i define a way that the array should look?

```
let spesificLayoutOfUnits =[ UnitMass.grams, UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.metricTons, UnitMass.stones, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.ounces ]
var toBeSorted = [ UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.metricTons, UnitMass.ounces, UnitMass.grams ]
```

I use the spesificLayoutOfUnits array as an array of all of the options the user has. Then add units form this array to the toBeSorted array which is the array of the chosen units.

```
var options = spesificLayoutOfUnits as! [UnitMass]
var tempArray = [UnitMass]()
while toBeSorted.endIndex > positionOfUnit {
   tempArray.append(toBeSorted.removeLast())
}
toBeSorted.append(options.remove(at: positionOfUnit))
while !tempArray.isEmpty {
    toBeSorted.append(tempArray.removeLast())
}
```

Comment: If the array is hard coded then just add the values in that order to start with, if it is not hard coded then please explain a little more what you want to do.

Comment: The array that i want to have sorted is starting like this always: [ UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.stones, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.ounces ], but when a switch is flicked it will remove the unit or add it, and I'm struggling to place the unit in the right place if for example (toBeSorted[0] remove, and then add a new unit.) everything is okay as long as nothing is removed. i have added my code for adding. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I would say, if those are the only possible denizens of the array, don’t add or remove anything. Just toggle whether each element is effective or not. Still unclear what the real goal is, but that’s my initial thought. In other words, keep two lists, the one you have, and the one that says which ones to filter out.

Comment: The way i have done it is that i use the toBeSorted array and then create an stackview containing a textfield and a label. but if the user holds on a button it will create a stackview of the spesificLayoutOfUnits array that contains a switch and a label. @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest building up a dictionary that maps UnitMass to its desired position and then using that for the sort:

```
let specificLayoutOfUnits = [ UnitMass.grams, UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.metricTons, UnitMass.stones, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.ounces ]

// Create a dictionary to map UnitMass to Int position   
var position = [UnitMass : Int]()

for (idx, um) in specificLayoutOfUnits.enumerated() {
    position[um] = idx
}

var toBeSorted = [ UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.metricTons, UnitMass.ounces, UnitMass.grams ]

// Sort the array by position.  Use Int.max if the UnitMass has no
// position to sort it to the end of the array
let sorted = toBeSorted.sorted { position[$0, default: Int.max] < position[$1, default: Int.max] }
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. calling `.enumerated()` on the `specificLayoutOfUnits` creates a list of tuples where the first element is the position and the second is the unit: `[(0, UnitMass.grams), (1, UnitMass.kilograms), (2, UnitMass.metricTons), ...]`.
2. Next, we iterate through this list to build up a dictionary that maps the unit to its position: `[UnitMass.grams: 0, UnitMass.kilograms: 1, UnitMass.metricTons: 2, ...]`
3. This dictionary is used to sort the second array by the elements position in the first.  `.sorted(by:)` takes a closure that compares two elements and returns a `Bool` which says if the first element is ordered before the second.  Here, we use the position of the two elements in the first array to decide the order.  Note that it is possible to have an element in the second array that doesn't appear in the first.  In that case, we use the special version of the dictionary lookup to return `Int.max` for the position.  This will cause all `UnitMass` values without a position to be sorted to the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you that works great. I'm struggling to understand how it works though, could you explain it to me? @vacawama

Comment: I added an explanation.  Let me know if I need to further clarify.

Comment: Thank you that grate @vacawama